# WINMAIN and main() in C++ (Extended)

Tags: c++, windows, program-entry-point, winmain

Right, I have looked at this post: [Difference between WinMain,main and DllMain in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416739/difference-between-winmain-main-and-dllmain-in-c)

I now know that `WINMAIN` is used for window applications and `main()` for consoles. But reading the post doesn't really tell me why exactly what is the difference.

I mean what's the point of having separating different mains functions to start of a program? Is it due to performance issues? Or what is it?

Comment: Depends what you want passed into your application. `int main()` is always allowed as an entry point according to the standard, though, along with `int main(int, char**)`.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

## About the functions.

The C and C++ standards require any program (for a “hosted” C or C++ implementation) to have a function called `main`, which serves as the program's **startup function**. The `main` function is called after **zero-initialization** of non-local static variables, and possibly but not necessarily (!, C++11 §3.6.2/4) this call happens after **dynamic initialization** of such variables. It can have one of the following signatures:

```
int main()
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
```

plus possible implementation-defined signatures (C++11 §3.6.1/2) except that the result type must be `int`.

As the only such function in C++ `main` has a **default result** value, namely 0. If `main` returns then after the ordinary function return `exit` is called with the `main` result value as argument. The standard defines three values that guaranteed can be used: 0 (indicates success), **`EXIT_SUCCESS`** (also indicates success, and is  typically defined as 0), and **`EXIT_FAILURE`** (indicates failure), where the two named constants are defined by the `<stdlib.h>` header which also declares the `exit` function.

The `main` arguments are intended to represent the **command line arguments** for the command used to start the process. `argc` (argument count) is the number of items in the `argv` (argument values) array. In addition to those items `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be 0. If `argc` > 0  – which is not guaranteed! – then `argv[0]` is guaranteed to either be a pointer to an empty string, or a pointer to the “name used to invoke the program”. This name may include a path, and it may be the name of the executable.

Using the `main` arguments to obtain the command line arguments works fine in *nix, because C and C++ originated with *nix. However, the *de facto* Windows standard for the encoding of the `main` arguments is **Windows ANSI**, which does not support general Windows filenames (such as, for a Norwegian Windows installation, filenames with Greek or Cyrillic characters). Therefore Microsoft chose to extend the C and C++ languages with a Windows-specific startup function called **`wmain`**, which has wide character based arguments encoded as **UTF-16**, which can represent any filename.

The `wmain` function can have [one of these signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), corresponding to the standard signatures for `main`:

```
int wmain()
int wmain( int argc, wchar_t* argv[] )
```

plus a few more that are not especially useful.

I.e., `wmain` is a direct wide character based replacement for `main`.

The **`WinMain`** `char` based function was introduced with Windows, in the early 1980's:

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE   hInstance,
    HINSTANCE   hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR       lpCmdLine,
    int         nCmdShow
    );
```

where `CALLBACK`, `HINSTANCE` and `LPSTR` are defined by the `<windows.h>` header ([`LPSTR` is just `char*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945990/difference-between-char-and-lpstr-in-windows)).

Arguments:

- the `hInstance` argument value is the base address of the memory image of the executable, it's primarily used to load resources from the executable, and it can alternatively be obtained from the `GetModuleHandle` API function,
- the `hPrevInstance` argument is always 0,
- the `lpCmdLine` argument can alternatively be obtained from the `GetCommandLine` API function, plus a bit of weird logic to skip the program name part of the command line, and
- the `nCmdShow` argument value can alternatively be obtained from the `GetStartupInfo` API function, but with modern Windows the first creation of a top level window does that automatically so it's not of any practical use.

Thus, the `WinMain` function has the same drawbacks as standard `main`, plus some (in particular the verbosity and being non-standard), and no advantages of its own, so it's really inexplicable except possibly as a vendor lock-in thing. However, with the Microsoft tool chain it makes the linker default to the GUI subsystem, which some see as an advantage. But with e.g. the GNU toolchain it does not have such an effect so this effect cannot be relied on.

The **`wWinMain`** `wchar_t` based function is a wide character variant of `WinMain`, in the same way as `wmain` is a wide character variant of standard `main`:

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(
    HINSTANCE   hInstance,
    HINSTANCE   hPrevInstance,
    PWSTR       lpCmdLine,
    int         nCmdShow
    );
```

where `WINAPI` is the same as `CALLBACK`, and `PWSTR` is simply `wchar_t*`.

There is no good reason to use any of the non-standard functions except the least known and least supported of them, namely `wmain`, and then just for convenience: that this avoids using the `GetCommandLine` and `CommandLineToArgvW` API functions to pick up UTF-16 encoded arguments.

To avoid the Microsoft linker acting up (the GNU toolchain's linker doesn't), just set the `LINK` environment variable to `/entry:mainCRTStartup`, or specify that option directly. This is the Microsoft runtime library entry point function that, after some initialization, calls the standard `main` function. The other startup functions have corresponding entry point functions named in the same systematic way.

---

## Examples of using the standard `main` function.

Common source code:

*foo.cpp*

```
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    MessageBox( 0, L"Press OK", L"Hi", MB_SETFOREGROUND );
}
```

In the examples below (first with the GNU toolchain and then with the Microsoft toolchain) this program is first built as a **console subsystem program**, and then as a **GUI subsystem program**. A console subsystem program, or in short just a **console program**, is one that requires a console window. This is the default subsystem for all Windows linkers I've used (admittedly not a great many), possibly for all Windows linkers period.

For a console program Windows creates a **console window** automatically if needed. Any Windows process, regardless of subsystem, can have an associated console window, and at most one. Also, the Windows command interpreter waits for a console program program to finish, so that the program's text presentation has finished.

Conversely, a GUI subsystem program is one that doesn't require a console window. The command interpreter does not wait for a GUI subsystem program, except in batch files. One way to avoid the completion wait, for both kinds of program, is to use the `start` command. One way to present console window text from a GUI subsystem program is to redirect its standard output stream. Another way is to explicitly create a console window from the program's code.

The program's subsystem is encoded in the executable's header. It's not shown by Windows Explorer (except that in Windows 9x one could “quick view” an executable, which presented just about the same information as Microsoft's `dumpbin` tool now does). There is no corresponding C++ concept.

### `main` with the GNU toolchain.

```
[D:\dev\test]
> g++ foo.cpp

[D:\dev\test]
> objdump -x a.exe | find /i "subsys"
MajorSubsystemVersion   4
MinorSubsystemVersion   0
Subsystem               00000003        (Windows CUI)
[544](sec -1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000004 __major_subsystem_version__
[612](sec -1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000003 __subsystem__
[636](sec -1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 __minor_subsystem_version__

[D:\dev\test]
> g++ foo.cpp -mwindows

[D:\dev\test]
> objdump -x a.exe | find /i "subsys"
MajorSubsystemVersion   4
MinorSubsystemVersion   0
Subsystem               00000002        (Windows GUI)
[544](sec -1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000004 __major_subsystem_version__
[612](sec -1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000002 __subsystem__
[636](sec -1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 __minor_subsystem_version__

[D:\dev\test]
> _
```

### `main` with Microsoft's toolchain:

```
[D:\dev\test]
> set LINK=/entry:mainCRTStartup

[D:\dev\test]
> cl foo.cpp user32.lib
foo.cpp

[D:\dev\test]
> dumpbin /headers foo.exe | find /i "subsys"
            6.00 subsystem version
               3 subsystem (Windows CUI)

[D:\dev\test]
> cl foo.cpp /link user32.lib /subsystem:windows
foo.cpp

[D:\dev\test]
> dumpbin /headers foo.exe | find /i "subsys"
            6.00 subsystem version
               2 subsystem (Windows GUI)

[D:\dev\test]
> _
```

---

## Examples of using Microsoft’s `wmain` function.

The following main code is common to both the GNU toolchain and Microsoft toolchain demonstrations:

*bar.cpp*

```
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

#include <string>       // std::wstring
#include <sstream>      // std::wostringstream
using namespace std;

int wmain( int argc, wchar_t* argv[] )
{
    wostringstream  text;

    text << argc - 1 << L" command line arguments:\n";
    for( int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i )
    {
        text << "\n[" << argv[i] << "]";
    }

    MessageBox( 0, text.str().c_str(), argv[0], MB_SETFOREGROUND );
}
```

### `wmain` with the GNU toolchain.

The GNU toolchain doesn't support Microsoft's `wmain` function:

```
[D:\dev\test]
> g++ bar.cpp
d:/bin/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa3): undefined reference to `WinMain
@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[D:\dev\test]
> _
```

The link error message here, about `WinMain`, is because the GNU toolchain does support *that* function (presumably because so much ancient code uses it), and searches for it as a last resort after failing to find a standard `main`.

However, it's trivial to add a module with a standard `main` that calls the `wmain`:

*wmain_support.cpp*

```
extern int wmain( int, wchar_t** );

#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>    // GetCommandLine, CommandLineToArgvW, LocalFree

#include <stdlib.h>     // EXIT_FAILURE

int main()
{
    struct Args
    {
        int n;
        wchar_t** p;

        ~Args() {  if( p != 0 ) { ::LocalFree( p ); } }
        Args(): p(  ::CommandLineToArgvW( ::GetCommandLine(), &n ) ) {}
    };

    Args    args;

    if( args.p == 0 )
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return wmain( args.n, args.p );
}
```

Now,

```
[D:\dev\test]
> g++ bar.cpp wmain_support.cpp

[D:\dev\test]
> objdump -x a.exe | find /i "subsystem"
MajorSubsystemVersion   4
MinorSubsystemVersion   0
Subsystem               00000003        (Windows CUI)
[13134](sec -1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000004 __major_subsystem_version__
[13576](sec -1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000003 __subsystem__
[13689](sec -1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 __minor_subsystem_version__

[D:\dev\test]
> g++ bar.cpp wmain_support.cpp -mwindows

[D:\dev\test]
> objdump -x a.exe | find /i "subsystem"
MajorSubsystemVersion   4
MinorSubsystemVersion   0
Subsystem               00000002        (Windows GUI)
[13134](sec -1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000004 __major_subsystem_version__
[13576](sec -1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000002 __subsystem__
[13689](sec -1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 __minor_subsystem_version__

[D:\dev\test]
> _
```

### `wmain` with Microsoft’s toolchain.

With Microsoft's toolchain the linker automatically infers the `wmainCRTStartup` entry point if no entry point is specified and a `wmain` function is present (it's unclear what happens if a standard `main` is also present, I haven't checked that in recent years):

```
[D:\dev\test]
> set link=/entry:mainCRTStartup

[D:\dev\test]
> cl bar.cpp user32.lib
bar.cpp
LIBCMT.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
bar.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

[D:\dev\test]
> set link=

[D:\dev\test]
> cl bar.cpp user32.lib
bar.cpp

[D:\dev\test]
> _
```

With a non-standard startup function such as `wmain` it is, however, probably best to specify the entry point explicitly, so as to be very clear about the intention:

```
[D:\dev\test]
> cl bar.cpp /link user32.lib /entry:wmainCRTStartup
bar.cpp

[D:\dev\test]
> dumpbin /headers bar.exe | find /i "subsystem"
            6.00 subsystem version
               3 subsystem (Windows CUI)

[D:\dev\test]
> cl bar.cpp /link user32.lib /entry:wmainCRTStartup /subsystem:windows
bar.cpp

[D:\dev\test]
> dumpbin /headers bar.exe | find /i "subsystem"
            6.00 subsystem version
               2 subsystem (Windows GUI)

[D:\dev\test]
> _
```

Comment: Can anyone update the link of valid `winmain()` signatures?

Comment: @jvriesem: `WinMain` has only one valid signature and so also `wWinMain`. However, `wmain` is like standard `main`, only with wide string arguments. That means it supports `int wmain()`, `int wmain( int, wchar_t** )` like standard `main`, and `int wmain( int, wchar_t**, wchar** )` as an extension. The 3ʳᵈ argument, typically called `envp`, is a pointer to environment variable strings where “This array is terminated by a NULL entry” according to [current Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=vs-2019). Now silly SO refuses more text, so.

Answer (score 15):

According to @RaymondChen

[The name WinMain is just a convention](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061204-01/?p=28853)

> Although the function WinMain is documented in the Platform SDK, it's
> not really part of the platform. Rather, WinMain is the conventional
> name for the user-provided entry point to a Windows program.
>
> The real entry point is in the C runtime library, which initializes
> the runtime, runs global constructors, and then calls your WinMain
> function (or wWinMain if you prefer a Unicode entry point).

DllMain and WinMain is different in their prototypes itself. WinMain accepts commandline argument while the other one talks about how it's attached to the process.

As per [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx)

By default, the starting address is a function name from the C run-time library. The linker selects it according to the attributes of the program, as shown in the following table.

- `mainCRTStartup` (or `wmainCRTStartup`) An application using
  `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE;` calls main (or `wmain`)
- `WinMainCRTStartup` (or `wWinMainCRTStartup`) An application using
  `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS;` calls `WinMain` (or `wWinMain`), which must be
  defined with `__stdcall`
- `_DllMainCRTStartup` A DLL; calls `DllMain`, which must be defined with `__stdcall`, if it exists

Answer (score 4):

A standard C program is passed 2 parameters by the command line at start up:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ) ;
```

- `char** argv` is an array of strings (`char*`)
- `int argc` is the number of `char*` in argv

The booting function `WinMain` that programmers have to write for a windows program is slightly different.  `WinMain` takes 4 parameters that are passed to the program by Win O/S at start up:

```
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,    // HANDLE TO AN INSTANCE.  This is the "handle" to YOUR PROGRAM ITSELF.
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,// USELESS on modern windows (totally ignore hPrevInstance)
                    LPSTR szCmdLine,        // Command line arguments.  similar to argv in standard C programs
                    int iCmdShow )          // Start window maximized, minimized, etc.
```

See my article [How to create a basic window in C](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/01/31/how-to-create-a-basic-window-in-c/) for more

Comment: -1 several wrong claims: "have to write", nope. "passed ... by Win O/S", nope. in addition a bit of terminology: "booting function", nope.

Comment: Well, "have to write" is wrong because you can always use a standard `main` for an application, regardless of Windows subsystem. "passed ... by Win O/S" is wrong because those parameters are not passed by the OS. they're passed by the entry point function, which fetches the information from the OS e.g. by calling `GetCommandLine`. "booting function" is misleading because there's no booting involved.

Comment: It seems to me that the answer is useless. QA asked what's the difference and you say about the differences in function signature. Isn't it obvious?

Answer (score 4):

The Windows CRT exposes 5 symbols `mainCRTStartup`, `wmainCRTStartup`, `wWinMainCRTStartup`, `_DllMainCRTStartup` and `WinMainCRTStartup`.

[image]

The `w` before means the unicode version, i.e. the command line (command and argument string) passed to the process (and stored in the PPB `PEB->ProcessParameters->CommandLine`) is UTF-16 (i.e. `WCHAR` (**W**ide char)) rather than ASCII (UTF-8 or ANSI e.g. Windows-1252, Windows-850 etc.)

If the `/DLL` or `/SUBSYSTEM` option is not specified, the MSVC linker selects a subsystem and entry point i.e. makes the entry address one of those 5 functions based on whether `main`, `WinMain` or `DllMain` is present in the symbol table of one of the object files. The entry point is [statically linked by the MSVC linker via `libcmt.lib`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66469163/7194773), which will further only include symbols that are actually used by that entry function.

`mainCRTStartup` will call `GetStartupInfo()` / access the PPB to get stdin/out handles and command line arguments. `_init term()` is also called, as well as `_init_atexit()`. It calls `main` The return value of `main` is passed to `ExitProcess()` after the set `atexit` routine is called.

Debug symbols in a .pdb created by using the `/Zi` compiler option are needed to be loaded in IDA Pro in order to reveal symbols such as `mainCRTstartup` and `main`, which will without debugging symbols instead be represented as `start` and `sub_??????` respectively.

Reference:

- [/ENTRY (Entry-Point Symbol) | Microsoft Docs § Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol#remarks)

Answer (score 2):

I vaguely recall reading somewhere that Windows programs have a `main()` function. It is just hidden in a header or library somewhere. I believe this `main()` function initializes all of the variables needed by `WinMain()` and then calls it.

Of course, I'm a WinAPI noob, so I hope others who are more knowledgeable will correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If this is true and my thinking is correct, this means we can hide console window without `-mwindows`, by simulating what the "hidden `main()`" does.

Answer (score 0):

I had an exe using _tWinMain and Configuration Properties.Linker.System.Subsystem: Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS). Later I wanted it to support cmdline args and print to the console so I added:

```
// We need to printf to stdout and we don't have one, so get one
AllocConsole();
// Redirect pre-opened STDOUT to the console
freopen_s((FILE **)stdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
```

but that only worked by printing in another console window that went away so was not that useful. Below is the way I changed it to work with Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) in such a way as I could go back and forth, if I needed to.

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(argc);
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(argv);
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(envp);
  return (_tWinMain(NULL, NULL, ::GetCommandLineW(), 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Main vs WinMain

As I have read from many links:

`WinMain()` is the `C` entry point function of any windows application. Like normal `DOS/console` based application which has `main()` function as `C` entry point, in windows we have `WinMain()` instead. `WinMain()` is a function which is called by system during creation of a process.

First argument is the instance handle of the current process.

Next is the previous instance.

Command line arguments comes as next argument.

Finally shell passes the show/display attribute of main window.

Note : WinMain returns success as zero and error as non zero.