# Compile error with winmain and simple code, "Previous decleration of WinMain"

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, winmain

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <windows.h>
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    return(0);
}
```

I'm new to C. The above code returns the following error when I try to compile:

```
main.c:3:5: error: conflicting types for 'WinMain'
 int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
     ^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:44:0,
                 from main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1263:14: note: previous declaration of 'WinMain' was here
 int APIENTRY WinMain (HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int);
```

Comment: where do you put the code above? is it above main?

Comment: I have no main. Do I need one? The above code is the entire code of my project. @AsafItach

Comment: The same error still occurs.

Comment: windws.h is a header file that lets you compile a program for windows, according to wikipedia it automatically includes windef.h, which defines HINSTANCE. Manually including windef.h does not resolve the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the function definition match the library's declaration. You have

```
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
```

and this needs to be

```
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
```

It is missing that `APIENTRY`.