# What / where is __scrt_common_main_seh?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

A third party library in my program is trying to call `__scrt_common_main_seh` by way of the Microsoft library `msvcrt.lib`, but is defined by some unknown library and therefore gives a linker error. I don't know what this function is supposed to do or where it is defined.

I looked online for this function, but did not find any clues except for general descriptions of what linker errors are.

I believe it might be doing some setup for win32 GUI applications. The library which defines it might be configured as project dependency by Visual Studio but my project is using Bazel.

Comment: This seems relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934206/what-is-the-difference-between-main-and-maincrtstartup

Comment: Also relevant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=msvc-160

Comment: `__scrt_common_main_seh` is the C and C++' language runtime startup code, that ultimately runs your code under a global SEH exception filter. When your code fails in catastrophic ways you'll at least get some error diagnostics out of it. It's totally unclear from the question, what situation you are in, but it is clear that your [proposed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64994218/1889329) is guess-work, at best. There's an old saying among native developers that goes something like this: If you don't know why your code works, it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @IInspectable. I think you are in a good position to improve on my answer. You might be able to explain what the SEH exception filter is, how exactly it comes to be instantiated, and under which circumstances the linker would not be able to locate it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Summary

For non-console applications having error `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)"` try adding linker flag `/ENTRY:wWinMainCRTStartup` or `/ENTRY:WinMainCRTStartup`

For console applications having that error, make sure to implement a `main()` function.

### Details

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55336931/353407) shows that `__scrt_common_main_seh` is normally called during `mainCRTStartup` which is the default [entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=msvc-160)  for windows **console** applications. `__scrt_common_main_seh` is then (indirectly) responsible for calling `main()`.

My program did not have a `main()` function, which might have prevented the compiler from generating `__scrt_common_main_seh` (Just speculating. I am totally clueless about who defines `__scrt_common_main_seh`)

I did find, however, that the library I was linking against defined a `wWinMain()` function. So I tried adding the linker flag `/ENTRY:wWinMainCRTStartup` and the linker error went away.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to add: `/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup` to the linker flags (`wWinMainCRTStartup` or `WinMainCRTStartup` did not work).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39704287/7683041.

Answer (score 2):

A bug in the Qwt qmake files. The author ( = me ) does not use Windows at all and missed, that "win32:CONFIG += entrypoint" seems to be necessary since Qt6.

See https://sourceforge.net/p/qwt/git/ci/qwt-6.2/
In case it doesn't work for you: https://sourceforge.net/p/qwt/bugs/365/