# Qt Windows application linker error: unresolved symbol _WinMain

Tags: windows, qt

I am building a Windows application based on Qt using VisualStudio 2017 Professional (15.9.35) and the Qt VS Tools add-on. The project compiled fine up to a certain point, now the linker gives the error:

```
10>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
```

The target Qt version is Qt-5.12.10-msvc2017-32 (my application is 32-bit). My application defines main(), I expect WinMain to be defined by Qt which in turn will call my main() (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689162/qt-project-in-visual-studio-2015-unresolved-external-symbol-wwinmain), it worked at earlier stages of the development)

What I've checked (in the project for the application, and also in the dependency libraries project that are in the same VS solution):

- Qt modules: core;gui;testlib;widgets
- Subsystem: Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)
- Character Set: blank (it's not either "Not set", it's set that way by the Qt VS Tools add-on when first creating a project)
- Treat wchar_t as built-in type: Yes (/Zc:wchar_t)

Comment: Not an answer, but I also tried moving a qt (built with qmake) to VS for a bit. Took a long while to get it working, and then it broke often whenever I wanted to use another qt feature. After adding and having issues with qt resources I reluctantly switched back to Qt Creator. Might be a better experience if you're using cmake though.

Comment: Take a look at https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-93671 - maybe it fits to your problem.

Comment: You need to link to the qtmain library. [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmain.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmain.html) not sure why this is not happening. I use CMake to generate my Qt + Visual Studio projects since 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in test builds using GitHub Actions for Windows and Qt 6, but at the same time the program built for Windows and Qt 5 without problems. Building for Linux and macOS was successful in any configuration. This was doubly strange because in another project using Qt the build completed successfully in any configuration.

I [removed](https://github.com/u-235/edytornc/commit/52e6f138879801f0acc78572ce53124b646755c8) the
`CONFIG += qt`
lines in the qmake scripts and the build succeeded for Windows and Qt 6.