# Detecting -mconsole and -mwindows in compilation

Tags: gcc, compile-time, windows-console

Probably this is an easy or stupid question, but I cannot find the answer:
Is it possible to check at compile time, if GCC on Windows is called with the -mwindows or the -mconsole option? I would like to direct output to stdout or to a message box, depending on this option, like

#ifdef CONSOLE_BUILD

printf( "Hello on stdout" );

#elifdef GUI_BUILD

     MessageBoxW( NULL, L"Hello on GUI", NULL, MB_OK );

#endif

Comment: Judging from [this post](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2004-01/msg00225.html) there's difference in `__subsystem__` symbol, worth checking it out.

Comment: Judging from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13872211/7034621) `-mconsole` results in `__subsystem__` being `3` and `-mwindows` - `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-mconsole` and `-mwindows` only affect the linker, not the compiler.  You could use a GCC specs file to add `-DCONSOLE_BUILD` whenever `-mconsole` is specified, but that would essentially be a custom GCC modification.

As an alternative, there seem to be various ways to figure out if a console window is associated with a process, for example the [`GetConsoleWindow` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow) (but I'm not a Windows programmer).

Comment: The way with GetConsoleWindow works! And, of course, directing output at runtime is even preferable to doing it on compile time.

Comment: @MartinSander please consider accepting the answer if it answers your question.