# Getting undefined reference error while running a project in C++

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error in C++ in VsCode. When I try to run this code(It's a very basic code):

```
#include <iostream>


int main()

{
    std::cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
undefined reference to 'WinMain@16' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know there are some solutions for this error in this forum but I still can't get it fixed because I'm new on C++ and I'm trying to learn it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the main-function. Try `int wmain()`.

Check up on main-functions in c++ under windows [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871617/winmain-and-main-in-c-extended)

Comment: `int wmain()` didn't worked and I still don't know how to solve this problem. Like what I said I'm new on C++ so I really can't understand what are them in the links. I tried to run this code in eclipse and it worked but the problem is I want to use VS code. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling this as a console-application? the main-function for a window-application would look like this:
`int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow);`

Comment: @SyntaxError Happy to help ;)